# Getting Text to sit over a video tag without using absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I'm trying to get some text to sit over a video without using absolute positioning. I'm trying to avoid absolute positioning because I have some menu items above my text set to justify-content: space around; and if I set the text to absolute positioning and give it a %offset left or right, the items above move out of sync with the text inside of the video. Here is the html im working with

```css
.service-tabs-group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.service-tabs-group div div:last-child {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.media-section-group {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

video.background-video {
  width: 100%;
}

.field.field--field_mediatitle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 35%;
  top: 10%;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #f47b20;
}
```

```html
<div class="service-tabs-group">
  <div class="tab-1-group">
    <div class="field field--field_tab1type">
      <img class="program-details">
    </div>

    <div class="field field--field_tabtitle">
      Program Details</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-2-group">
    <div class="field field--field_tab2type">
      <img class="process">
    </div>

    <div class="field field--field_tab2title">
      EPD Process</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-3-group">
    <div class="field field--field_tab3type">
      <img class="benefits">
    </div>

    <div class="field field--field_tab3title">
      Benefits</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="media-section-group">
  <div class="field field--field_mediatitle">
    See what our clients are saying about us</div>

  <div class="field field--field_backgroundvideo">
    <video class="background-video" src="http://domain.dd:8082/files/lake_and_clouds_test1.1.mp4" poster="/files/bendingthecurve.jpg" autoplay="" loop="">
      <img src="/files/bendingthecurve.jpg">
    </video>
  </div>

  <div class="field field--field_mediaimage">
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried setting the text that's supposed to go over the video to display block, with a text align attribute, which centers it. Then I give it a - margin-bottom, which should send it down and over the video, but instead it always gets tucked behind the video. Anyone know why it is tucking behind and not over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relatively/static positioned elements have their [stacking order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) determined by the order in which they appear in the DOM. Lower elements have a higher stacking order, so your video container is going to display "over" its previous sibling elements.

Absolute positioning is really the way to go here. The code you've posted seems to work fine in my local testing.